# Adding datafile affect on index? (oracle)

Tags: oracle

Recently my oracle datafiles are getting scarce,
so that I've added large size of datafiles to table space.

Then, some index became unused out of sudden...
And the program-performance got worse.

Does anybody know such case that Adding datafile affect index-usage?

Answer (score 1):

No.  Data file operations and index operations are completely separate.  Likely the two occurrences are coincidental, but unrelated.

Comment: @user3377721,  Application processes/data flows can be very complex.  You can instrument every step in the application process to see where this happens.  For example, if index was marked unusable for a load, then the load failed and index not reset/rebuilt.